# Word web Add-in: detect document Close

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, office-js-helpers, word-web-addins

I'm developing a Word Add-in (Word API + Office.js) and I'm wondering if it's possible to get notified when the user click on Close button of word application

Currently my word template has few content controls with data, i am saving the content control data to database when the cursor comes out of the control.

i am trying to implement the same logic when the user click on Close button.

so want check whether Word API has a way to track user click on Close button? Thanks!

Comment: There is no such event of that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no way yet to handle that event in Office.js. But it's a great idea. Please go to Office Developer Suggestion Box and vote up [this suggestion](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33088858-no-events-for-standard-operations-like-document-cl).